# How to write L2-softmax loss in Keras?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, face

A **Tensorflow** version is like this:

```
fc1 = alpha * tf.divide(fc1, tf.norm(fc1, ord='euclidean'))
```

But how can I use **Keras** to write a **L2-softmax** like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`tf.divide(fc1, tf.norm(fc1, ord='euclidean'))` normalizes `fc1` tensor.

In Keras you can do this with `keras.backend.l2_normalize`.